# How to trim string between given parameter from existing string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, replace, trim

I have the string `"/Employee/Details/568356357938479";` and I want to obtain the new string of only `"/Employee"` from the given string?

```js
var myString = "/Employee/Details/568356357938479";
var newString = myString.replace(/\\|\//g, '');
```

I'm expecting : `"/Employee"`

Comment: [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) would work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var myString = "/Employee/Details/568356357938479";
var newString = myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf("/", 1));
console.log(newString);
```